Changing tab color in macro by checking text value in worksheet
I managed to get help with creating a macro that changes the tab color when i change a value in the worksheet. However i have to manually the change value for the macro to pick up the change to a different color. That may have been done purposefully when created but now wondering if thats possible so the macro works automatically once the value changes automatically in the worksheet rather than me changing the value in the worksheet manually. Below is the code:
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    If Target.Address = "$J$4" Then
    Select Case Target.Value
        Case "Done"
            Me.Tab.Color = RGB(0, 176, 240)
        Case "In progress"
            Me.Tab.Color = RGB(255, 255, 0)
        Case "Not started"
            Me.Tab.Color = RGB(225, 225, 225)
        Case "Waiting for documentation"
            Me.Tab.Color = RGB(112, 173, 71)
        Case "Need further work on"
            Me.Tab.Color = RGB(255, 192, 0)
        Case "Not Applicable"
            Me.Tab.Color = RGB(166, 166, 166)
        End Select
    End If
End Sub

Many thnx
This code works but when i create a formula for the value in the worksheet to update automatically, the code doesn't pick that up as the formula in the cell doesnt change. How can make the macro look at the actual text?

If a cell value is calculated via formula, either you need to check in the change trigger if any of the cell was changed that calculates that value, or you need to use the Worksheet_Calculate-Trigger. See for example https://stackoverflow.com/a/78539260/7599798

Please share the formula in J4.
